# Trying to space grid of checkboxes in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I want two lines of equally spaced checkboxes. (seven per row first line with captions MON-SUN second row no caption)

I have a span around each of the checkboxes.  If I set the
`Style="display: inline-block; width: 30px"`
it does what I expect, but when I create a rule in my stylesheet:

```
.ckwidth {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
}
```

and then set the class="ckwidth" on the spans it seems to ignore the rule.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. By what you state in your question, there seems to be other styles with a higher specificity than a simple CSS class definition, overriding (parts of) your code. Did you check with the element explorer in your browser's developer tools (F12 on Windows)?

Answer (score -2):

Try out this, might help.
if this don't work then share your code.

```
.dis-flex {
    display: flex !important;
//or
display: inline-flex; 
 .ckwidth {
   margin: auto;
   width: 30px;
  }
}
-----------or----------------
.row {
   margin: auto;
 .ckwidth {
 display: flex !important;
   width: 30px;
  }
}
```